# Limiting a multi table update with mysql

Tags: mysql

I am aware that adding a limit and order by to a multi-table update is not inherently allowed with SQL. However I have the following query:

```
        UPDATE msh_leads ml
            LEFT JOIN msh_leads_disposition_log dl
            ON ml.id = dl.lead_id
            SET ml.assigned_to = null
            WHERE ((dl.disposition_id != 6 AND dl.disposition_id != 3) OR (dl.disposition_id IS NULL))
                AND (ml.assigned_to = ? AND ml.decline = 0 AND ml.subcategory_id = ?)
```

I need to add a limit to this. There are a few articles out there on how to do this but each of them uses their own custom query custom coded for their original query and I can't discern a pattern. Can anyone figure out how i can add a limit to this?

Comment: Maybe add a different column with a flag enforced by a trigger which should specify which rows will be updated.Anyway what is the criteria for this limit?

Comment: I cannot use triggers. Technically this query removes leads of a certain category and a certain disposition from a user.....the user can choose from 25 / 50 / 200 or ALL as a limit. So if the user selects to take away 25 leads then it should ONLY update the first 25 leads.

Comment: Im not sure it can be done,AFAIK LIMIT variables in mysql cannot be parametrized.The only thing I can think of is to write 4 different queries and check in your application which one the client is choosing and fire that.How will such a query look ,here is an example http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/08/10/how-to-use-order-by-and-limit-on-multi-table-updates-in-mysql/

Comment: that isn't my issue. My limit is dynamic already. My issue is that when you have an UPDATE with a JOIN in it you can no longer use LIMIT at all. There are a lot of questions on it. There are workarounds but none of them are ones that would work for my specific situation. Also I already saw that blog...he builds his query from the ground up knowing about this limitation. I need someone that converts an existing update / join / limit into this format so i can replicate